# Solution of $dX_{t}=(sin(X_{t})+2)dB_{t}$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am curious if $dX_{t}=(sin(X_{t})+2)dB_{t}$ has a solution i.e $X_{t}$=(stuff in terms of $B_{t}$).

What about for $dX_{t}=\sigma(X_{t})dB_{t}$, where $0<\gamma^{-1}\leq \sigma\leq \gamma<\infty$?

This is related to another question of finding cardinality of $dX_{t}=\sigma(X_{t})dB_{t}$. So I wanted an example to help me make sense of it.

Thank you

Comment: How do you define "closed form"? You can certainly rewrite it in the form $$f(B_t)-\int_0^t g(B_s) \, ds$$ for some functions $f$ and $g$...

Comment: I changed it. I am bit confused about this topic (I thought they were solutions to SDEs in not a closed form)